# Extracting Data From A Dictionary for if check

Tags: python, dictionary

```
{u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'text': u'@Kor3aYn @YouTube yeet', u'is_quote_status': False, u'in_reply_to_status_id': 805863281042878464L, u'id': 805864211544965122L, u'favorite_count': 0, u'source': u'<a href="http://twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web Client</a>', u'retweeted': False, u'coordinates': None, u'timestamp_ms': u'1480967974922', u'entities': {u'user_mentions': [{u'id': 4249141216L, u'indices': [0, 8], u'id_str': u'4249141216', u'screen_name': u'Kor3aYn', u'name': u'YOUTUBE: Kor3aYn\U0001f1f0\U0001f1f7'}, {u'id': 10228272, u'indices': [9, 17], u'id_str': u'10228272', u'screen_name': u'YouTube', u'name': u'YouTube'}], u'symbols': [], u'hashtags': [], u'urls': []}, u'in_reply_to_screen_name': u'Kor3aYn', u'id_str': u'805864211544965122', u'display_text_range': [18, 22], u'retweet_count': 0, u'in_reply_to_user_id': 4249141216L, u'favorited': False, u'user': {u'follow_request_sent': None, u'profile_use_background_image': False, u'default_profile_image': False, u'id': 4858458939L, u'verified': False, u'profile_image_url_https': u'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/728320215986114560/f12oxR9J_normal.jpg', u'profile_sidebar_fill_color': u'000000', u'profile_text_color': u'000000', u'followers_count': 148, u'profile_sidebar_border_color': u'000000', u'id_str': u'4858458939', u'profile_background_color': u'000000', u'listed_count': 0, u'profile_background_image_url_https': u'https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', u'utc_offset': None, u'statuses_count': 76, u'description': None, u'friends_count': 21, u'location': u'Nuk3town', u'profile_link_color': u'ABB8C2', u'profile_image_url': u'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/728320215986114560/f12oxR9J_normal.jpg', u'following': None, u'geo_enabled': False, u'profile_banner_url': u'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/4858458939/1454015440', u'profile_background_image_url': u'http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png', u'name': u'Smye', u'lang': u'en', u'profile_background_tile': False, u'favourites_count': 64, u'screen_name': u'i_Smye', u'notifications': None, u'url': None, u'created_at': u'Thu Jan 28 20:59:06 +0000 2016', u'contributors_enabled': False, u'time_zone': None, u'protected': False, u'default_profile': False, u'is_translator': False}, u'geo': None, u'in_reply_to_user_id_str': u'4249141216', u'lang': u'en', u'created_at': u'Mon Dec 05 19:59:34 +0000 2016', u'filter_level': u'low', u'in_reply_to_status_id_str': u'805863281042878464', u'place': None}
```

I have the following in an array stored as decoded. I'm trying to get the ['id_str'] which is two things; the tweetID and the user ID.

```
if ScreenName not in decoded['user']['screen_name']: #if your name is not in the json   
     if decoded['id_str'][1] == Twitter_ID: # lets say 4858458939
```

This is what I have and I understand it it not correct. I'm essentially trying to get the author of the tweet which I think is stored under the second 'str_id' and check if it == to my Twitter_ID variable.

Please could some assist me on what to do.
Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON? Your data given is a native Python data structure -- if it *used* to be JSON before you parsed it is moot; it's just regular Python data now.

Comment: I have changed the titles, thanks.

Comment: @smye It is not array (which is numpy array). This structure is dictionary in python.

Answer (score 0):

Biggest issue that I see is that `decoded['id_str']` is a string. This means `decoded['id_str'][0]` is a character in a string. You mean `decoded['id_str']`.

If that doesn't work, normally, for this type of conversion, there is a type casing risk. Are you sure that you're comparing ints to ints? Try this:

```
repr(decoded['id_str'])
```

If you're seeing `u'<number>'` (you should, based on the data you provided), then you don't have an integer, so comparing an integer won't work. This fails by design.

```
>>> unicode(2) == 2
False
```

If that is the case, you can cast as part of your comparison:

```
# Making sure that ScreenName is unicode to match encoding
if unicode(ScreenName) not in decoded['user']['screen_name']:
    # Making sure that twitter ID is an integer.
    if int(decoded['id_str']) == Twitter_ID:
```

You might be better off using `unicode(Twitter_ID)` if you're not positive that will always be numeric.

Comment: Yes, it's always comparing an int to an int. 
print (int(decoded['id_str'][1]))
I get a value of 0,  so the if check fails
I'm  sure this is the way to check for the owner of the tweet.